# WCF Service ask login and password

Tags: c#, wcf

Good day all

I have the following question: how to change web.config to ask for the credentials before user uses the service?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this helps [WCF username and password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733131.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do basic authentication for your purpose and disable all authentication from your IIS (Where your wcf will be hosted) except Basic Authentication

By default anonymous authentication is enabled that's why it will not ask when you access your service.

You need to do web.config setting also as per below

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
<binding name="myHttpGetBinding">
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
<transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
</security>
</binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
<endpoint address="yourserviceaddress"
binding="basicHttpBinding"
bindingConfiguration="myHttpGetBinding"
contract="BasicAuthTest.MyServiceContract"
name="myBasicEndpoint"/>
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Please refer following links

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFBasicHttpBinding.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/BasicAuthWCFRest.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817643.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since your service is hosted in IIS, you should check out the guidance provided in [this link](http://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20Security%20Practices%20at%20a%20Glance&referringTitle=Home), specifically the section on Authentication.

I believe that unless you have Windows Authentication turned on in IIS, which will automatically prompt the user, your application will be responsible for gathering the user's credentials.